# What is the most compact arrangement of superstrings?

Tags: string-theory, crystals, compactification

I was thinking about crystals and how they might apply to really dense arrangements of matter near the Big Bang or in collapsing stars.

It seems that the bosonic strings and superstrings can form crystalline arrangements that are in a sense maximally dense for their particular dimensions. Let us add a condition that no point on a string can come a distance of 1 Plank Length from any other. (In some sense string theory has a minimal distance as dimensions with size $R$ are dual to dimensions of size $1/R$. Thus we require the densest arrangement in the dual space also). One could invent some fictitious force that keeps strings at a minimal distance from each other for this thought experiment. Alternatively we might think of wave packets of strings which have a certain size.

1. Bosonic String Theory has 26 dimensions. Ignore 1 dimension of time. And wrap one dimension on a circle. You get 24 dimensions. Arrange an infinite array of closed strings in a 24D Leech lattice with each string wrapped around the compact 25th dimension.
2. Super String Theory has 10 dimensions. Ignore 1 dimension of time. And wrap one dimension on a circle. You get 8 dimensions. Arrange an infinite array of closed strings in a E8 lattice with each string wrapped around the compact 9th dimension.

One could make superpositions of all possible orientations and translations of the lattices. To get a state $|\psi\rangle$ which would seem to have particularly low entropy.

It seems like if you ask the question *"What dimensions of space and time would you need to arrange 1D strings in the densest arrangement?"* You find it must be 2 more than the dimension of the particularly dense sphere packing dimensions which are $8$ and $24$.

If you compactified some more dimensions down to 3, what would happen to these optimal arrangements?

Are the other optimal arrangements that don't involve compactifying one dimension?

Is there any thought about what these highly symmetrical crystalline arrangements of string might play in physics? (I know they are related to the Moonshine conjecture, but what about physics interpretations?)

Comment: open string endpoints lie on D-branes, then the real question asks for the most compact D-brane configuration, the answer to such question is always a black hole (by definition of a black hole). Notice that the answer is independent of the target spacetime.

Comment: A ball in $D$ dimensions is $D$ dimensional. A string in $D$ dimensions is one dimensional...